# How to use php artisan serve inside docker container?

Tags: laravel, docker

I create a php-composer image using dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install curl
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

And I run following commands to create a container and start a laravel app.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:8000 --name MyTest -dt php-composer to create a container
docker cp laravelApp/ d4bbb5d36312:/usr/
docker exec -it MyTest bash
cd usr/laravelApp
php artisan serve
```

After thet, container's terminal will show the success info:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

But when I access 127.0.0.1:3000 at local browser, I get nothing.

So is it possible that simply run php artisan serve to start a laravel app inside docker container?

Or I must to using nginx or apache to run it?

Comment: You *should* use nginx or Apache, as the `php artisan serve` server isn't for use in production, and your development environment should be as close to production as possible.

Answer (score 25):

**This can be done so:**

```
$ docker container run -it --rm -v /host/path/laravel:/app -p 3000:8000 php bash
$ cd /app
$ php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

By default containers start in `bridge` network, inside which the host available by the address `0.0.0.0`.

> When you start Docker, a default bridge network (also called bridge) is created automatically, and newly-started containers connect to it unless otherwise specified.

[https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

**Or so (only Linux):**

```
$ docker container run -it --rm --network host -v /host/path/laravel:/app php bash
$ cd /app
$ php artisan serve (or php artisan serve --port 3000)
```

> If you use the host network driver for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host.

[https://docs.docker.com/network/host](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the issue with two commands:

1. Run this on the host machine to check if the port mapping is correct:

   `docker port MyTest`
2. Run this on the host machine to check the output from inside your container:

   `docker exec MyTest curl 127.0.0.0:8000`
    
   You should see the raw HTTP response of your Laravel application.