# Docker not mapping external port on Windows 11

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I currently have docker set up to a stage where it running, however it is not mapping the external port. I am trying to connect to DummyService port 8020, localhost:8020, but it is unable to be reached.  Below is the the Docker config. Please advise on any fixes on this issue.

```
`version: '3.8'
services:
  dummyservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
    networks:
      - dummynetwork
    ports:
      - "8020:8000"
    depends_on:
      - dummy_db

  dummy_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dummy
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - dummynetwork
    volumes:
      - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "33020:3306"
networks:
  dummynetwork:
    external: true`
```

Here is the Docker file

```
FROM laravelphp/vapor:php81

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
RUN rm -rf ex.
COPY . .

RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

RUN composer install
RUN composer dump-autoload

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8000
```

I have tried getting the IP through Docker inspect and using the IP given through the Ipconfig.
The expected result is to communicate with Docker on the exposed port.

Comment: What error? On which service do you try to connect? DummyService or DummyDb? Witch port/command do you use? Please update the question with relevant info.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I am trying to connect to DummyService port 8020, localhost:8020, but it is unable to be reached.

Comment: What contains the Dockerfile of DummyService? The compose file is ok maybe is the app on DummyServer, please update the question with your comment above and the content of the Dockerfile of DummyService.

Comment: Hi @Max, I have updated the question with the docker file

Comment: Check if you have any error on the container log `docker container logs <yourcontainerid>`. Check also [this](https://buddy.works/guides/laravel-in-docker#write-a-dockerfile),and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369664/how-to-use-php-artisan-serve-inside-docker-container)