# How can I see real-time changes are done using Tailwind css with laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, docker, npm, tailwind-css

"I need to observe real-time CSS changes while working on Blade files. This project (Laravel 10) is Dockerized, and Tailwind configurations are set up correctly. However, CSS changes are not being displayed."

When I run npm run dev inside the Docker shell, nothing happens. Subsequently, running npm run build provides all the classes I've used, but it doesn't recognize any additions.

I need to display real-time css changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use php artisan serve inside docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369664/how-to-use-php-artisan-serve-inside-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) to bundle your application's CSS and JavaScript files.
vite.config.js exists by default in laravel project , just need to install and config it for real time changes.
this is example for vite.config , hope this helps you :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css', 
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

you can see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite) for more information